# how to keep the response.body() data of Retrofit onRespose() call in a singleton

Tags: java, android, singleton, retrofit, retrofit2

I tried to store the data from `response.body()` during a network call using retrofit. But I couldn't access the data using a singleton object.

**Here is my singleton class code:**

```
public class FishCategory {
    private SparseArray<String> sparseArray = new SparseArray<>(3);
    private static FishCategory singleton;

    public static FishCategory getSingleton() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new FishCategory();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    public SparseArray<String> getSparse() {
        ApiService service = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
        Call<CategoryResp> call = service.categoryAPI();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CategoryResp>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CategoryResp> call, Response<CategoryResp> response) {

                CategoryResp categoryResp = response.body();
                for (int i = 0; i < categoryResp.getsData().getCategoryList().size(); i++) {
                    sparseArray.put(i, categoryResp.getsData().getCategoryList().get(i).getCatTitle());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CategoryResp> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        return sparseArray;
    }
}
```

Now if I use this singleton object in a different class, it returns null.
PLEASE HELP....

Comment: how you are using this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `SharedPreferences` along with asynchronous call of `Retrofit` and problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
public SparseArray<String> getSparse() {
        ApiService service = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
        Call<CategoryResp> call = service.categoryAPI();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CategoryResp>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CategoryResp> call, Response<CategoryResp> response) {

                CategoryResp categoryResp = response.body();
                for (int i = 0; i < categoryResp.getsData().getCategoryList().size(); i++) {
                    sparseArray.put(i, categoryResp.getsData().getCategoryList().get(i).getCatTitle());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CategoryResp> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        return sparseArray;
    }
```

You are not creating non blocking coding in this case .Using `enqueue` you are shifting it to a separate thread while your code is still being executed which would obviously not wait for your code to execute.So your sparseArray is null.
Please use below for blocking nature and do note that below would be working on Main UI thread which would throw exception.

```
TaskService taskService = ServiceGenerator.createService(TaskService.class);  
Call<List<Task>> call = taskService.getTasks();  
List<Task>> tasks = call.execute().body();
```

Read below for understanding synchronous and asynchronous nature .
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests

```
    public SparseArray<String> getSparse() {
            ApiService service = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
            Call<CategoryResp> call = service.categoryAPI();
            call.execute().body();
            for( i = 0; i < categoryResp.getsData().getCategoryList().size(); i++) {
                        sparseArray.put(i, categoryResp.getsData().getCategoryList().get(i).getCatTitle());
            }
            return sparseArray;
        }
```

Comment: I tried your code too but still my singleton is showing null

Comment: Try the update .. on a separate thread it shouldnt give null .. Hope this solves your problem.. Please do study the link shared

Comment: u mean i should make a synchronous request.

Comment: Yes.. Please check the futurestud.io url